# changing the facet_wrap labels using labeller in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

In my `ggplot` below, I'm trying to change the 10 facet labels of `facet_wrap` using `labeller(sch.id=paste0("sch.id:", unique(ten$sch.id)))`.

However, the plot shows `NA` instead of the correct facet labels, I wonder what the fix is?

```
library(ggplot2)

hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')

ten <- subset(hsb, sch.id %in% unique(sch.id)[1:10])

p <- ten %>% ggplot() + aes(ses, math) + geom_point() +
 facet_wrap(~sch.id) + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)

p + facet_wrap(~sch.id, labeller = labeller(sch.id=paste0("sch.id:", unique(ten$sch.id)))) ## HERE ##
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to change `sch.id` before plotting.

```
library(ggplot2)
ten$sch.id <- paste0("sch.id:", ten$sch.id)

ggplot(ten) + aes(ses, math) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~sch.id)
```

[image]

---

If you don't want to modify your data and want to use the `labeller` argument you can create a named vector and use it in `labeller`.

```
cust_label <- setNames(paste0("sch.id:", unique(ten$sch.id)), unique(ten$sch.id))

ggplot(ten) + aes(ses, math) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~sch.id, labeller = as_labeller(cust_label))
```

Comment: sure, but the documentation supports using `labeller`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be that you are passing a variable to the labeller function but `facet_wrap` already passes its own faceting variable. A conflict occurs and the result are `NA`'s.
The solution is to create a labeller function as a function of a variable `x` (or any other name as long as it's not the faceting variables' names) and then coerce to labeller with `as_labeller`.

Note that there is no need for `unique`, just like there is no need for it in the `facet_wrap` formula.

```
p <- ten %>% ggplot() + aes(ses, math) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)

cust_labeller <- function(x) paste0("sch.id:", x)
p + facet_wrap(~ sch.id, 
               labeller = as_labeller(cust_labeller)) ## HERE ##
```

[image]